# Develop Node.js / React application on a remote server, and access it locally

Tags: node.js

I would like to remotely work on (or develop) a React application, but still check the results in a local browser. Using `npm`, on the remote server, I launch

```
npm start
```

in order to start the application.

It returns

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
```

Then, locally, I can access to the application in my browser at the address `machineIP:1234` where `machineIP` is the IP address of the remote host. This looks convenient, but I do not want to expose my application to the entire world.

I am actually very surprised that the port 1234 is suddenly open to anyone. Maybe this is a configuration of my remote server under Ubuntu 19.04.

I see two potential directions:

1. Can I prevent the port 1234 to be opened to the outside? And then open an SSH tunnel from my local host to the remote host on the (now private) port 1234?
2. I could restrict the access to the application with a password, but after every restart of the application (because it is being modified on the server), I might have to log in every time.

How would you proceed to privately check your application (in your local browser) while it is running (and being constantly restarted) on a remote server?

Comment: Why do you need to do development on a live remote server?  Can't you develop your server locally or in a virtual machine?

Comment: I want to access the development environment from different computers. Also, one of the local computers is old and very slow, so that even my text editor is sometimes freezing for a second (e.g., when node.js is recompiling). At some point, I was also lacking space on my disks because of the huge requirements of node.js (in node_modules or .cache).

Comment: So does this reduce down to the problem of:  there is an application running on port 1234 on a remote machine and you don't want to allow any other machines to access it except yours?  Or is it more like you don't want to allow any other _users_ to access its features except you? (I think I'm asking you to choose between 1 and 2 for whcih one you want answered)

Comment: Answer to #1:  https://askubuntu.com/a/875227/822409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you may want to check if there is a firewall running on that remote server. If there isn't, then [`ufw`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall) is probably a good option. Make sure to `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp` or `sudo ufw allow OpenSSH` before `sudo ufw enable` so you can still SSH into the server. You can also choose to allow connections to port 1234 from your own local IP using `sudo ufw allow from localIP to any port 1234`, where `localIP` is the public IP address of your local machine. Then you can simply go to `machineIP:1234` in your browser to view your application.

If you don't want to or can't open port 1234 to your own IP, but do still have SSH access, then you can also set up an SSH tunnel using `ssh -L 1234:machineIP:1234 machineIP`. Then you can view your application by going to `localhost:1234` in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I work a lot with node and react and I a tool to solve this problem for me.
it is self-hosted and free, it use ssh but helps you with a UI

https://github.com/vicjicaman/tunnel-tool

If you need any help let me know!